# Form text field variable is showing undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, variables, undefined

This is my first post, anyway I'll get straight to the point.

I have a form that when a user writes they're name in, Javascript saves the value to the global variable "ch_name". When I access this variable through an alert at any point on the site it always shows the correct value that I entered. However, it only works for alerts, when I try reference the user by using the variable it always shows as undefined.

I've tried re-ordering the code in case it hadn't loaded correctly and this hasn't yielded any results either. I've begun wondering whether I've referenced it right at all as I'm still fairly new to JavaScript.

As you'll probably find out my code is a mess but here's what I've got.

```
var ch_name; //my global variable

var data = new Array(); //I've taken a snippet out of an array of 8.
data[0] = '<p>Question 1</p>' + ch_name + "\n" + //ch_name is referenced on this line.
'<button onclick="results1()">Click Me</button>' + "\n" + 
'<button onclick="results2()">Click Me</button>' + "\n" +
'<button onclick="results3()">Click Me</button>';

function charName(form) { //This is the code that changes the global variable ch_name.
ch_name = document.nameform.user.value;
ranData = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = data[ranData];
}
```

The html snippet:

```
<form NAME="nameform" method="GET">
<p>Enter your character name:</p> <input type="text" name="user" value="" />
    <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="charName(this.form)"/>
</form>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Referencing the ch_name through an alert anywhere gives me the correct result, blank on page load and after the string is entered it gives the correct name. But anytime I reference it through the array variable it shows an undefined. This is not the full code but I'm certain there's no conflicts in variable names etc. I've scanned it a good few times, I'm certain it's just me being an idiot.

Is there a work around for this? I'm in a place ready to drop the whole code behind ch_name entirely to focus on other areas of the page.

Thanks for reading and any help.

Comment: `document.nameform.user.value` does this work? Because name attribute is depreceated http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8

Comment: Not certain Carl, my friend told me it was the issue too but I'm trying to work out a way around it. I'm not going to lie, I didn't really understand that link you gave me. I did a little research on forms beforehand and this was the code people were using, I must have turned up some very old webpages.

Comment: Just checked that. It will work for forms though it might be removed in the future. Don't try accessing names on other element though. But yeah the code should run.

Comment: Quick question though. You know when you add `ch_name` to `data[0]` like that the value of `data[0]` doesn't change when `ch_name` changes? It only takes the value of `ch_name` when it was set i.e. null

Comment: That's what it seems to be doing yes, I completely forgot I was trying to change the variable data[0]'s value to some html + another variable. I'm trying to refresh it like Xymostech suggested but now I'm not getting any undefined or anything there.

Comment: Added an answer which hopefully shows you how to dynamic update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data won't change the way you seem to think.

I think for you the best bet would be to replace `data` Array with a function.

Now the `ch_name` parameter will be created dynamically every time you run the function. i.e. every time the button is pressed, which will update the data.

How do you change the data in a page?

```
var ch_name; //my global variable
function charName(form) { //This is the code that changes the global variable ch_name.
    ch_name = document.nameform.user.value;
    ranData = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = getranData(ranData);
 }

function getranData(num){
   if(num==0)
          return '<p>Question 1</p>' + ch_name + "\n" + //ch_name is referenced on this line.
          '<button onclick="results1()">Click Me</button>' + "\n" + 
          '<button onclick="results2()">Click Me</button>' + "\n" +
          '<button onclick="results3()">Click Me</button>';
  else if (num==1) ; ///...and so on
}
```

Comment: The data is collected through a button, I may replace this with an img at some point but a button works fine for now. I have good feeling this will work, I'm setting it up to test now I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that when your `data` array is generated, `ch_name` doesn't have a value, so it comes out as blank. Even when you change `ch_name`, the `data` value won't be re-generated with the correct value.

A solution to this might be having a `regenerate_data` function that re-generates your data `data` array whenever you change the global character name.

Comment: I think this is the problem but I can't work out how to refresh it, I've tried adding a function that runs whenever I want ch_name to be referenced, that function re-attains the value from the form and uses the document.write command but now it's not showing at all. Can you offer me some guidance to get a refresh that'll work?